# Update custom listview item attribute

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using listview in my app.I am adding items to list with this line:

```
conversationsAdapter.add(user);
```

and this initializes list

```
conversationsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<JsonObject>(this,0) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int c_position,View c_convertView,ViewGroup c_parent) {
        if (c_convertView == null) {
            c_convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars,null);
        }
        JsonObject user=getItem(c_position);
        String name=user.get("name").getAsString();
        String image_url="http://domain.com/photos/profile/thumb/"+user.get("photo").getAsString();
        TextView nameView=(TextView)c_convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweet);
        nameView.setText(name);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)c_convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Ion.with(imageView)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.twitter)
        .load(image_url);
        return c_convertView;
    }
};
ListView conversationsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.conversationList);
conversationsListView.setAdapter(conversationsAdapter);
conversationsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        startChat(conversationsAdapter.getItem(position));
    }
});
```

My list view is looking like this:

[image]

I want to update an item in the list.How can I do this ?

Example:We can write a method like: `changeName` when this method calls,method sets name "Tolgay Toklar" to "Tolgay Toklar Test" so I want to update custom listview item attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally disagree with tyczj.  You never want to externally modify an ArrayAdapter's list and yes it's possible to update just an individual item.  Lets start with updating an individual item.

You can just invoke `getItem()` and directly modify the object and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  Example:

```
JSONObject object = conversationAdapter.getItem(position);
object.put("name", data);
conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Why does this work? Because the adapter will feed you the same object reference used internally, allowing you to modify it and update the adapter.  No problem. Of course, I'd recommend instead building your own custom adapter to perform this directly on the adapter's internal list.  As an alternative, I highly recommend using the [ArrayBaseAdapter](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) instead. It already provides that ability for you while fixing some other major bugs with Android's ArrayAdapter.

So why is tyczj wrong about modifying the external list? Simple. There's **no** guarantee that your external list is the same as the adapters.  Once you perform a filter on the ArrayAdapter, your external list and the adapters are no longer the same.  You can get into a dangerous scenario where *(for example)* index 5 no longer represents position 5 in the adapter because you later added an item to the adapter.  I suggest reading [Problems with ArrayAdapter's Constructors](http://jaysoyer.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/problems-with-the-arrayadapter-the-constructors/) for a little more insight.

**Update: How External List Fails**

Lets say you create a List of objects to pass into an ArrayAdapter. Eg:

```
List<Data> mList = new ArrayList<Data>();
//...Load list with data
ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(context, resource, mList);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So far so good.  You have your external list, you have an adapter instantiated with it and assigned to listview.  Now lets say at some later point, the adapter is filtered and cleared.

```
adapter.filter("test");
//...later cleared
adapter.filter("");
```

Now at this point `mList` is **NOT** the same as the adapter.  So if the adapter is modified:

```
adapter.add(newDataObject);
```

You'll find that mList does not contain that new data object.  Hence why external lists like this *can* be dangerous as the filter creates a **NEW** ArrayList instance. It won't continue to use your `mList` referenced one. You could even try adding items to `mList` at this point and it won't be reflected in the adapter.

Comment: what exactly do you think notifyDatasetChanged() does? it updates the adapter with the new data. I also said you need to find the correct object in the list that needs modification, there is no chance that the positions are incorrect when you find the object you want in the list and replace it.

Comment: They *may* if you are modifying the external list as you suggested.  Check out the source code to an ArrayAdapter's filter. You'll see that there internal lists will get new List reference.  So while the objects they store are the same...the List of themselves are not: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter

Comment: @JaySoyer I used like this:http://prntscr.com/4i220l  but I am getting this error:The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type JsonObject How can I fix it ?

Comment: @JaySoyer Also can you look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576877/update-an-item-in-the-arrayadapter

Comment: You should be using the `JSONObject` class. Ie: `import org.json.JSONObject;`

Comment: @TolgayToklar, that SOF answer by Squonk is spot on and he provides another additional reason why you shouldn't keep an external list as suggested by tyczj. However I did edit Squonks answer with an example for a minor performance improvement.  Nothing big, just a nice FYI really.  Will need to wait until he approves the edits for it to be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the data in your list you need to call `notifyDatasetCanged` on the adapter to notify the list that the underlying data has changed needs to be updated and.

**Example**

```
List<MyData> data = new ArrayList<MyData>();

private void changeUserName(String name){
    //find the one you need to change from the list here
    .
    .
    .
    data.set(myUpdatedData);
    notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

Comment: I know it.I am asking how can I change data in my list.

Comment: what do you mean, you have your data somewhere just change it where you hold your data

Comment: I am holding it in conversationsAdapter  but I don't know how can I update an item.Can you give an example ?

Comment: see my edit. without see how you save the data i cant really do much more

Comment: But I want to change spesific item.How can I do it ?

Comment: you dont change a specific item you change the data in the list you refresh the data. the item you need to change may or may not be visible which is why you dont change a single item

Comment: I am developing chat app.When user receives a message I have to show user who sent the message.Like "Tolgay Toklar (1)" how can I do this ?

Comment: Like i said hold the data in a list then change the data item in the list then you update the adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60266/discussion-between-tolgay-toklar-and-tyczj).

Comment: @tyczj I disagree.  Externally modifying an ArrayAdapter's list is dangerous. Posted an alternative answer to this

Comment: @tyczj, negative. You are saying to modify an external List of the adapter. I'm saying to retrieve an item from the adapter and update that instead.  No external list

Comment: @JaySoyer it is exactly the same thing! the list you create is references in the adapter so you are essentially changing the same list

Comment: @tyczj, I'll update my answer to show you an example of how it fails