# Update an item in the arrayadapter

Tags: android

I have an arrayadapter.I can add items to this arrayadapter,but sometimes I need the update an item in this adapter.I researched the internet and can't find anything about update specific item in the adapter  then I did like this:

```
Integer test=randomAdapter.getPosition(user);
randomAdapter.remove(user);
randomAdapter.insert(updated_user,test);
randomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In this code `user` is a jsonobject.I am getting position of this item then I am removing it and adding uptated user data into old object position.This seems works.But I don't know this is a good idea for update an item so I am asking to you.

If this is a bad idea,how should be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ArrayAdapter` maintains a reference to the array or `List` of objects that it uses. Any of the methods such as `add(...)`, `remove(...)` or `insert(...)` act directly on the array /  list and also used `synchronized` statements making them thread-safe.

Your approach may seem slightly long-winded but it's as safe a way of doing things as any other way. You could, of course, manipulate the original array / list yourself but if you need thread-safety you'd have to add synchronization to your own code. Why re-invent the wheel?

If you want to look at the source code for `ArrayAdapter` it's [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)

Comment: I don't know what is the synchronized statements,but if my approach is safe,I will use this method.Thank you

Comment: @TolgayToklar : Search Google for "Java synchronization". It's a way to create synchronized methods or statements that 'lock' and prevent more than one `Thread` from performing the same action at the same time. Your code works in a safe way and I can't see a problem with it.